# When clicking a tag element in the preview of a post I am writing, shouldn't the default be to open that tag in a new tab?

Tags: feature-request, tags, posting

The title pretty much is all I am asking.

I was just writing an answer in which I wanted to use a tag [like-this](/questions/tagged/like-this).
I wasn't sure if I spelled it correctly hence I clicked it, and rather than opening a new tab it was a redirect in that same window. But if someone is creating a post, is there ever a reason, why someone might want to discard his writing, just to check a part of that "to be written" post?
(I think it is same for links by the way)

Comment: You can always Right Click (If you're using a mouse), then press: "Open link in new tab". It works for me.

Comment: @StackExchangeTornado ofc I can do that. But my point is, why you ever wanted to left click it with current behavior? So why not make it have a useful behavior instead?!

Comment: I also thought of that too, that can also be annoying when I forget to right click. That is why I agree with this.

Comment: When you click on the tag, don't you get a popup window warning you are leaving the page? This would prevent anyone from accidentally losing their half-written answer.

Comment: @DavidK: True, I do. But when I made this meta post I acidently clicked the tag twice (thought I missed it the first time) and in my writing the tag was exactly on the height the "leave anyways" button appeared. I don't say this is a bad design in itself. It was just a very rare and unfortunate case. BUT:

Comment: My point isn't that there are no safety measures, to prevent loosing the content. My point here is, there is not a single use-case I could consider that would ever come up, where someone would want to discard his work, just to check a part of their work. So it is not an complaint about the measures being taken to warn the user, it is, in such scenario there wouldn't ever be a logic reason to click "yes, leave anyways". And hence, why not just in that specific case, remove the feature at all and instead make left click an open in new tab event. I tried to be clear about it in OP. Should I edit?